New player as a DM?
Basically I am starting a D&D group.
None of know how to play.
I have read through most of the starter set rulebook.
Should I DM or should we just wait until we find someone who has a bit of experience?

Welcome Matthew to your first question! :) Hopefully you'll find the link that Joakim posted helpful. The question you posed if more of a question to post in a D&D interest group/forum. No-one can answer that question as we can tell you whether you should or shouldn't without it being an opinion. Have a look at the stack for other questions that support how to broach being a new DM and the DMG has lots of helpful tips, too. :)

Hi Matthew. I edited your post because it was poorly written.  I suggest that you take the [Tour], and then review the [Help], [Ask] and [Answer] to get the most out of this SE site.
